# Including external dll's into my class library dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll

If I want to make a library (say for a bunch of Google APIs), then my library has a lot of dependencies in the form of dll's coming from Google. Is it possible to link the whole bunch including my code into ONE dll, so that I don't need to reference all the google dll's separately in other projects using the library?

Comment: With a not managed dll I add it as a resource and load it dinamically at runtime. With managed dll you can use ILMerge http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iLMerge tool for this. iLMerge is a tool provided by Microsoft.

Download it from here

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17630